# Is there a way to prove that these series do not converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was looking at the real part of the Dirichlet eta function, defined as $\mathbb{R}[\eta(a+bi)]=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos(b\ln(n))}{n^a}}$, with $0<a<1$ and $b>0$.

I then split this series into odd and even terms:

$\mathbb{R}[\eta(a+bi)]=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{\cos(b\ln(2k-1))}{(2k-1)^a}-\frac{\cos(b\ln(2k))}{(2k)^a}\right]}$

I graphed the truncated versions of these two series separately in the $XY$-plane, as

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{x+1}{2} \rfloor} \frac{\cos(b\ln(2k-1))}{(2k-1)^a}}$

and

$\displaystyle-{\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor} \frac{\cos(b\ln(2k))}{(2k)^a}}$

for different values of $a$ and $b$.

From my graphs, it seems that as $x$ approaches infinity, the absolute value of both of these series tends to increase without bound, although not monotonically. Is there a way to prove that these series do indeed diverge?

My thought is that it has something to do with $\cos(b\ln(2k-1)$ and $\cos(b\ln(2k))$ changing increasingly slowly, thus creating longer strings of adding values of the same sign as $k$ increases.

Comment: Would this not follow from the fact that (for $0<a<1$) $\eta(a+bi)$ converges but does not converge absolutely?

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense.